# How to draw semi ellipsoid clamp to ground

Tags: javascript, geometry, cesiumjs

Here, i am using the below code for 3D map. And this creates semi ellipsoid below the ground surface in case of terrain area.

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain(),
});

viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableCollisionDetection = false;

var radiusX = 720;
var radiusY = 720;
var radiusZ = 600; // radius in the up direction

var entityPosition = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(82.88827, 39.50256, 0 );

viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.DebugModelMatrixPrimitive({
            modelMatrix : Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(entityPosition),
            length : radiusZ,
            width : 1.0
        }));

var entiti_ellipsoid = viewer.entities.add({
      position: entityPosition,
      ellipsoid: {
        radii: new Cesium.Cartesian3(radiusX, radiusY, radiusZ),
        maximumCone: Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO,
        material: Cesium.Color.fromRandom({ alpha: 0.5 }),
        //clampToGround: true,
       // heightReference: Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
      },
    });

viewer.zoomTo(entiti_ellipsoid);
```

Attaching the output snippet below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

```
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
        terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain(),
    });

    viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
    viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableCollisionDetection = false;

    var longitude = 82.88827;
    var latitude = 39.50256;

    var radiusX = 720;
    var radiusY = 720;
    var radiusZ = 600; // radius in the up direction

    viewer.camera.flyToBoundingSphere(new Cesium.BoundingSphere(Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude, 1000), radiusZ * 2));

    var drawn = false;

    viewer.scene.globe.tileLoadProgressEvent.addEventListener(function (queuedTileCount) {
        if (drawn)
            return;

        console.log(queuedTileCount);
        console.log(viewer.scene.globe.tilesLoaded);

        if (viewer.scene.globe.tilesLoaded) {
            var height = viewer.scene.globe.getHeight(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude));

            console.log(height);

            var entityPosition = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude, height);

            viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.DebugModelMatrixPrimitive({
                modelMatrix: Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(entityPosition),
                length: radiusZ,
                width: 1.0
            }));

            var entiti_ellipsoid = viewer.entities.add({
                position: entityPosition,
                ellipsoid: {
                    radii: new Cesium.Cartesian3(radiusX, radiusY, radiusZ),
                    maximumCone: Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO,
                    material: Cesium.Color.fromRandom({alpha: 0.5}),
                    //clampToGround: true,
                    // heightReference: Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
                },
            });

            drawn = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, its working on 2D map. But on 3D, its going under the ground. So i also need the same on terrain area. Please suggest in that scenario

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: ok. let me modify my answer.

Comment: would be thankful if you accept and mark my answer